# как передать массив данных в вид в codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

коллеги! Подскажите, пожалуйста, как в Codeigniter передать массив данных из модели в вид!?))
Имеем следующую ситуацию:

====  Модель ====

```
        $query = $this->db->query('SELECT name, others FROM customers');
        $data = $query->result();
        return $data;
```

передаю в Контроллер:

```
public function index(){

        $this->load->model('model_information');
        $data = $this->model_information->index();

        $this->load->view('test',$data);

    }

здесь функция print_r выводит все как надо...
```

..но в виде:

```
<h1>Hello</h1>

    <?=$name?>


<?php print_r($data);?>
```

Кидает такие портянки:

=============================================
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: name

Filename: views/test.php

Line Number: 4

Backtrace:

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\Test\application\views\test.php
Line: 4
Function: _error_handler

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\Test\application\controllers\IndexCompany.php
Line: 34
Function: view

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\Test\index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once

==================================================

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: data

Filename: views/test.php

Line Number: 18

Backtrace:

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\Test\application\views\test.php
Line: 18
Function: _error_handler

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\Test\application\controllers\IndexCompany.php
Line: 34
Function: view

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\Test\index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once

================================================

уже третий день ищу ответ - и  все впустую((((((((((

т.е. в КОНТРОЛЛЕРЕ надо определять переменные - тогда они нормально заходят в ВИД!!
А если данные приходят с МОДЕЛИ, то как их показать ВИДУ??? особенно если это массив!!!
Как-то переопределять или....??? Вообщем: подскажите, пожалуйста, если кто знает!!) 
Спасибо!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тут конечно приходится идти наощупь, но `$data` это массив массивов, индексирован он скорее всего с нуля, потому во вьюху передается нечто типа:

```
$this->load->view('test', [
    0 => ['name' => '', 'others' => ''],
    1 => ['name' => '', 'others' => ''],
    2 => ['name' => '', 'others' => ''],
]);
```

И вот вопрос - где тут хоть что-то напоминающее `$data` или `$name`. Ответ простой - **нигде**.

Чтобы обратиться к именованным переменным их естественно надо назвать, поэтому:

```
$this->load->view('test', ['data' => $data]);
```

Вот теперь во вьюхе будет доступен массив результатов в переменной `$data`, переменная называется `$data` именно потому, что ключ в массиве, передаваемом во вьюху, называется так же - `data`. И так как это массив - по нему надо проитерироваться с помощью `foreach`.

Comment: Аааа!!!))) Понятно!! СпААААсибище ООООгромное!!! ...и, соответственно, к переменной $name уже обращаемся как $data[0]->name; Точно!